# On excel: UI Ribbon: How to unpress a toggle button?

Tags: button, toggle

I have an excel application that has 5 selectable buttons (togglebuttons). I want when one is pressed, it will turn off the one that is pressed. Right now it only works by detecting that another one is on, and sends a message to the user to turn it off (it's kinda lame that way).

Thanks in advance for the replies!

I tried to look it up, I saw that there is an InvalidateControl function, but I don't really understand how I should call it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.